# How to find a decomposition of a module

Tags: abstract-algebra

$R=M_{n,n}(K)$ is a ring and $R$ is a left-Modul over itself.

How can I find a decomposition of $R$ as direct sum of Indecomposable modules?

I would like to find an example, Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is $K$? A field?

Comment: @rschwieb yes, $K$ is a field

Comment: Thanks, but then the *very next thing* you should do, provided it doesn't invalidate existing answers, is to *add that to your question*.

Answer (score 1):

If $K$ is a field, you can just verify that the set of column vectors $K^n$ operated on the left by elements of $R$ forms a simple left $R$ module, and then you can conclude that

$$
R=\oplus_{i=1}^n C_i
$$

where $C_i$ is the subset of matrices which are zero outside of column $i$. All of the $C_i$'s are isomorphic to the simple left module I mentioned earlier.